# ColReorder makes table's each column width increase

Tags: jquery, datatables

When I use datatables version 1.10.0 and ColReorder version 1.1.1,
reordering column makes any column of table increases

Is there way to fix or work around this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "scrollX": true,
        "dom": 'Rlfrtip'
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78A3t/)

Answer (score 0):

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/61042/#Comment_61042

in Glebst's answer, it says this is a bug and the solution is:

in file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DataTables-1.10.0/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

in line:

```
var t = (th.attr('style') || '').match(/width:\s*(\d+[pxem%])/);
```

replace by

```
var t = (th.attr('style') || '').match(/width:\s*(\d+(px|em|%))/);
```